# Mysql, querying varchar column with like gives no result

Tags: mysql, sql

In Mysql database, I have a table. Columns are id (int), name (varchar 40). The name column has a couple of cells with just 'NO' strings stored.

Why do I get nothing in return if I query something like below?

```
select * 
from TABLE_NAME 
where name like '%NO%'
```

or

```
select * 
from TABLE_NAME 
where name = 'NO'
```

Any help for the drowning?

Comment: Update a random row `SET name = 'NO'` and try the second select again.

Comment: Are you sure that they are "NO" without any characters within them ?  Try '%n%' just to prove it.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, when i inserted a new row (can't update because all the other linked tables may go crazy), i could run both the queries and they produced what i needed. any idea why this happens?

Comment: @RohitGupta, with '%n%' it does work. any ideas why this happens?

Comment: That mean there are some characters between `N` and `O`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
select 
     SUBSTRING(name, 1,1) AS value1,
     SUBSTRING(name, 2,1) AS value2,
     SUBSTRING(name, 3,1) AS value3,
     SUBSTRING(name, 4,1) AS value4,
     SUBSTRING(name, 5,1) AS value5,
     ASCII(SUBSTRING(name, 6,1)) AS value6
from TABLE_NAME
```

Then use [**ascII**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_ascii) function to see each character value.

Comment: Wondering, did you found what characters were in between `N` and `O` ?

Comment: it wasn't really the character between, it was that O was in ascii as 208 which is strange.

Comment: juan, if you could, maybe add also the query to get the name into the substring, like set @name = 'select name from TABLE_NAME where name = some identifier'. this will help newbies like me. :)

Answer (score 2):

You obviously have some character between N and O.  Using `'%n%'` search or something similar, I would update them to 'NO' .

Comment: how can i actually see if i have something in between N and O because in the command line output of mysql i just see NO in the cell, nothing more...

Comment: You cant necessarily as it may be a non-graphic character.  You can fetch it into a string and use php to convert it to hex for display.